# Using Expect to copy a file from one remote to another

Tags: shell, ssh, expect

I am trying to enable password-free ssh login among a cluster of hosts. So after I generate the id_rsa.pub by `ssh-keygen`, I wanna copy it to all the others by this command

- `ssh -t user_name1@client "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user_name2@server"`

This command works in shell but I just could not make it by `spawn` as expected. What am I currently trying is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#exp_internal 1
set user_name [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set client [lindex $argv 2]
set server [lindex $argv 3]

set timeout -1
spawn ssh -t $user_name@$client 
expect  {
    # first connection, no public key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    "yes/no" {
        send -- "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    # already has public key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    "password:" { 
        send -- "$password\r" 
    }
}
expect "$ "
send -- "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $user_name@$server\r"
expect  {
    "yes/no" {
        send -- "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "password:" { send -- "$password\r" }
}
```

I debugged it and found out that the last `sending` worked but the result is just unexpected as that in shell. I also tried to merge the `send -- "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $user_name@$server\r"` and `spawn ssh -t $user_name@$client` and then handle them both in a hierarchical expect-send way but the result is the same. The script just could not move further to complete the last `password` sending or we can say it that it could not send to the right channel. I am really confused right now.

Could someone help a little bit?

Really appreciate the help from you! Thank you so much!

If there are some good reference or tutorials on Expect, I will also really appreciate it for your sharing too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the `ssh-copy-id` command to finish, just like when you manually run the command.

```
expect -ex "$ "
send -- "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $user_name@$server\r"
expect  {
    "yes/no" {
        send -- "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "password:" { send -- "$password\r" }
}
expect -ex "$ "
```

Comment: Thank you @whjm it just works smoothly! It seems that last `expect "$ "` really means a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh-copy-id` and `sshpass` commands. 
Here is my oneline solution:
 
`` for i in `cat hosts.txt`; do sshpass -p YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $i; done ``